# White bar under footer in wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hey everyone I am having an issue with this wordpress site with underscore theme.
below the footer I have a white bar. I have combed through all elements can't seem to fix it. Can anyone help me out?

Here is the link-->  http://eajohnsongroupinc.com/

Thank you,
K.M.

Comment: does your link work? "This site can’t be reached - eajohnsongroupinc.com’s server DNS address could not be found."

Comment: it should i am able to reach it through my mobile device

Comment: Anyway reachable or not, we don't provide support from external resources. Please provide relevant code in your question and screenshots if necessary. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Ok sorry about that I am still fairly new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the last item in the footer `Powered by EZToUse.com`. If you remove this element everything is ok. I think that the paragraphs there have some margin/padding.

You can add to keep the link and fix the issue.

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: No problemo K.M. :)
Quiet down voter, please explain.

Comment: @StanimirStoyanov I did the downvote, for two reasons: 1. you just hide the problem without fixing the actual layout issue beneath, and 2. you provide an answer to a question that doesn't fit to SO and doesn't provide any [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please avoid answer such question and flag them instead accordingly.